# Triac switch cause of heating

Tags: transistors, switches, heat, triac, solenoid

As a newbie to hardware design, I'm having some trouble picking components. I want to switch a 24V AC Solenoid valve using a triac.
According to my research/experience, transistors heat up during use. However, I can not figure out what is causing this heating. Is it the small current at the Base that gets converted into heat? Because the collector and emitter will just act as a closed switch and no power will be lost there right? If not, what is causing energy to be converted to heat here?

Comment: I'll share some of my experience. I have used triacs in some of my projects and due to VxI power dissipation, the triac becomes quite hot at continuous currents >1A. I was not using any heat sink due to space constraints. In your application, also consider using a relay. If you still want to use a triac, see if you can use a heat sink to remove the excess heat.

Comment: @Whiskeyjack Thanks for sharing your experience! The Solenoid valve I am designing this for has an inrush current of 400mA and a holding current of 200mA. I have to verify that this will not generate too much heat, but my instinct says this should be fine. Since I will be creating a PCB that can switch 12 Solenoids, I would like to keep every switching circuit as small as possible, therefore, I decided to go with a triac instead of a relay.

Comment: 200 mA continuous current shouldn't be a problem. If you need to learn more about the circuit I used, you can follow this link - https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/368230/relay-sticking-when-switching-mains-for-led-power-supply/368300#368300

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The switch is not perfect, there is some voltage drop across is so power must be dissipated of load current x voltage drop. That's in addition to the base or gate power which is usually not very significant in a well-designed circuit.

For a triac the loss is usually of the order of 1W per ampere of load current (implying a voltage drop at typical currents of around 1V), but you should be able to find detailed curves and limits in the triac datasheet. See, for example, the [BT138](https://media.digikey.com/pdf/Data%20Sheets/NXP%20PDFs/BT138%20Series.pdf) (a 12A triac) datasheet, which shows typical voltage drop at 15A of 1.4V and maximum dissipation of about 6W at 5A RMS full conduction angle (Fig 1).

Comment: Thanks a lot for the detailed explanation Spehro! I had not thought about the voltage drop over the triac.  
But now I can use your example to calculate the power dissipation for my chosen triac and look up the corresponding heat dissipation in the datasheet!

Answer (score 1):

The title says you are asking about a triac but most of your post is about transistor heating.

> Because the collector and emitter will just act as a closed switch and no power will be lost there right?

No. Try measuring the colletor-emitter voltage when the transistor is turned on. You will find that it is probably about 0.2 V if you have adequate base current. Power dissipated from the collector current will be given by \$ P = V_{C-E}I_C \$.

Comment: My apologies, I was under the assumption that a thyristor was a subset of transistors. Thank you for your response, this voltage drop explains the heat dissipation.

Comment: No problem. See Wikipedia's [TRIAC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TRIAC) for details.